# Can I use PSR-7 StreamInterfaces with PHP's native stream functions?

Tags: php, stream, psr-7

I'm asking as I'm using packages like `im0rtality/jsonstreamingparser` that depend on the input being a native php stream, e.g. by calling `get_resource_type()`.

If not directly, is there any wrapper library on packagist that my search did not turn up?

Comment: Did you take a look for example at Zend\Diactoros? Its stream class, implementing StreamInterface, seems to do what you're looking for (https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diactoros/blob/master/src/Stream.php)

Comment: imho Diactoros is the other way round- expose a stream as StreamInterface?

Comment: yes, you're right, I didn't understand correctly your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`guzzle/psr7` provides the desired funtionality by its `StreamWrapper` class: https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/master/src/StreamWrapper.php